# How to swap two rows depending on the direction using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have a table where every record has two arrows one pointing to up and another one pointing to down, so

For example, if you click the up arrow in the third row that row must change position with the second one or if you click the down arrow it must change position with the fourth row

Right now what I have accomplished is to swap with the up arrow between rows but it's not working with the first row, if you click the up arrow in the first row it will take you down and that's an error, also the down arrow is not currently working on any row

```js
function getAbstractInSession(sessionId){
        var abstracts
        abstracts = [
            {
                Pos:"1",
                WAB:"Larry",
                Title:"The Bird"
            },
            {
                Pos:"2",
                WAB:"Messi",
                Title:"Thins"
            },
            {
                Pos:"3",
                WAB:"Hernandez",
                Title:"Cosa"
            },
            {
                Pos:"4",
                WAB:"Joseph",
                Title:"Tose"
            },
            {
                Pos:"5",
                WAB:"Alex",
                Title:"Today"
            }
        ]
        return abstracts;
    }
    
    function fillSessionTable(){
        select_session = document.getElementById("select-session").value;
        html = "";
        var records = this.getAbstractInSession(select_session);
        for(let item in records){
            html += "<tr>"+
                    "<td><strong>"+records[item].Pos+"</strong></td>"+
                    "<td><strong>"+records[item].WAB+"</strong></td>"+
                    "<td>"+records[item].Title+"</td>"+
                    "<td class='d-flex justify-content-around mb-0'>"+
                        "<div style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='moveRowUp(this)'>"+
                            "<i class='fas fa-chevron-up'></i>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "<div style='cursor:pointer;' onclick='moveRowUp(this)'>"+
                            "<i class='fas fa-chevron-down'></i>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "<div style='cursor:pointer;'>"+
                            "<i class='far fa-times-circle'></i>"+
                        "</div>"+
                    "</td>"+
                "</tr>"
        }
        document.getElementById("session-table").innerHTML = html;
    }

    function moveRowUp(element){
        var row = element.parentNode.parentNode,
        sibling = row.previousElementSibling,
        anchor = row.nextElementSibling,
        parent = row.parentNode;
        parent.insertBefore(row, sibling);
    }
```

```html
 <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
 <div class="col-7 h-100 px-0">
                    <select class="form-select mb-3" id="select-session" aria-label="Default select example" onchange="fillSessionTable()">
                        <option selected>Select a session from the list</option>
                        <option value="1">One</option>
                        <option value="2">Two</option>
                        <option value="3">Three</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="mt-2 mb-3">
                        <div class="tableFixHead">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Pos</th>
                                        <th scope="col">WAB #</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Abstract Title</th>
                                        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Actions</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody id= "session-table">

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                        <button class="btn bg-sl-orange text-white px-5">Assign</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

So what I have done until now is use a function that takes the clicked element: took the row, the previous element beside him and the next one and then use a `insertBefore()` function from js to make the swap

Comment: First, you can use indexing of element based on it you can disable/prevent moveUp operation for 1st element. Second, down button is triggering the same up button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to test if row.previousElementSibling or row.nextElementSibling are null ( I use `!!rowPrev` and `!!rowNext` )

sample code

```js
const abstracts = 
      [ { Pos: '1', WAB: 'Larry',     Title: 'The Bird' } 
      , { Pos: '2', WAB: 'Messi',     Title: 'Thins'    } 
      , { Pos: '3', WAB: 'Hernandez', Title: 'Cosa'     } 
      , { Pos: '4', WAB: 'Joseph',    Title: 'Tose'     } 
      , { Pos: '5', WAB: 'Alex',      Title: 'Today'    } 
      ] 

const sessionTable = document.getElementById('session-table')

abstracts.forEach(abst => 
  {
  let row = sessionTable.insertRow()
  row.innerHTML = `
      <td><strong>${abst.Pos}</strong></td>
      <td><strong>${abst.WAB}</strong></td>
      <td>${abst.Title}</td>
      <td class='d-flex justify-content-around mb-0'>
        <div> <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i> </div>
        <div> <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i> </div>
        <div> <i class='far fa-times-circle'></i> </div>
      </td>`
  })

sessionTable.onclick = ({target}) =>
  {
  if (!target.matches('i.fas, i.far')) return

  let row = target.closest('tr')
    , rowPrev = row.previousElementSibling
    , rowNext = row.nextElementSibling
    ;
  if (target.matches('i.fas.fa-chevron-up') && !!rowPrev)
    {
    sessionTable.insertBefore(row, rowPrev)
    }
  if (target.matches('i.fas.fa-chevron-down') && !!rowNext) 
    {
    sessionTable.insertBefore(rowNext,row)
    }
  if (target.matches('i.far.fa-times-circle'))
    {
    if (confirm(`delete ${row.querySelector('td:nth-of-type(2)').textContent} ?\nPlease confirm`))
      { 
      row.closest('table').deleteRow(row.rowIndex)
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
#session-table td:nth-of-type(4) {
  cursor : pointer;
}
#session-table td:nth-of-type(4) div:hover {
  color  : red;
}
#session-table tr:first-of-type td:nth-of-type(4) div:nth-of-type(1),
#session-table tr:last-of-type  td:nth-of-type(4) div:nth-of-type(2) {
  color          : lightgrey;
  pointer-events : none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">

<div class="col-7 h-100 px-0">
<div class="mt-2 mb-3">
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Pos</th>
        <th scope="col">WAB #</th>
        <th scope="col">Abstract Title</th>
        <th scope="col" class="text-center">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id= "session-table"></tbody>
  </table>
</div></div></div>
```