# How to dynamically add and delete items in a table on an expense tracker app using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I can add items onto my table however I cannot remove more than one row from the tr element that I am creating with the values from my input forms.  I have tried removing the delete buttons parent element and the delete buttons grandparent element, however when I click the delete button, only the last tr element gets removed.  I have also tried removing the rowElement variable that I have created but that only removes the last row as well, not the corresponding row of the delete button.  I need to find a way to connect each delete button to the corresponding tr element that it is in so that each delete button deletes the row that it is in.

html is:

```
<form>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="26" placeholder="Where was the expense made?" required>
        <br>
        <label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
        <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
        <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" required>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Expense" id="submit">
    </form>



    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name:</th>
            <th>Date:</th>
            <th>Amount:</th>
            <th>Remove:</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tBody">

        </tbody>
    </table>



    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

javascript is:

```
submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');
nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
dateInput = document.querySelector('#date');
amountInput = document.querySelector('#amount');
tBody = document.querySelector('#tBody');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addRow(nameInput.value, dateInput.value, amountInput.value);
});

let addRow = function (theName, theDate, theAmount) {
    rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
    nameElement = document.createElement('td');
    dateElement = document.createElement('td');
    amountElement = document.createElement('td');
    deleteElement = document.createElement('td');
    deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

    nameElement.textContent = theName;
    dateElement.textContent = theDate;
    amountElement.textContent = theAmount;
    deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete';

    deleteElement.append(deleteBtn);

    tBody.appendChild(rowElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(nameElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(dateElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(amountElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(deleteElement);

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        rowElement.remove();
    });

    nameInput.value = "";
    dateInput.value = "";
    amountInput.value = "";
}
```

This is what is broken

```
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        rowElement.remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent of an element is the one to use to remove it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode

I found a way to do it, by assigning an unique id to each row and use this to reference the row to delete.

```
<script>
submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');
nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
dateInput = document.querySelector('#date');
amountInput = document.querySelector('#amount');
tBody = document.querySelector('#tBody');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addRow(nameInput.value, dateInput.value, amountInput.value);
});

let addRow = function (theName, theDate, theAmount) {
    rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
    const idValue =  new Date().getTime(); //The getTime() method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.  // To enssure the is id unique
    rowElement.setAttribute('id', idValue)
    nameElement = document.createElement('td');
    dateElement = document.createElement('td');
    amountElement = document.createElement('td');
    deleteElement = document.createElement('td');
    deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

    nameElement.textContent = theName;
    dateElement.textContent = theDate;
    amountElement.textContent = theAmount;
    deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete';

    deleteElement.append(deleteBtn);

    tBody.appendChild(rowElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(nameElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(dateElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(amountElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(deleteElement);

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const referenceToElementForDeletion = document.getElementById(idValue);
        //rowElement.parentNode.removeChild(rowElement); // In this way it only deletes the last inserted element
        referenceToElementForDeletion.parentNode.removeChild(referenceToElementForDeletion);
    });

    nameInput.value = "";
    dateInput.value = "";
    amountInput.value = "";
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Also I found a way to do it without assigning an unique id.

```
    <script>
submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');
nameInput = document.querySelector('#name');
dateInput = document.querySelector('#date');
amountInput = document.querySelector('#amount');
tBody = document.querySelector('#tBody');

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    addRow(nameInput.value, dateInput.value, amountInput.value);
});

let addRow = function (theName, theDate, theAmount) {
    rowElement = document.createElement('tr');
    nameElement = document.createElement('td');
    dateElement = document.createElement('td');
    amountElement = document.createElement('td');
    deleteElement = document.createElement('td');
    deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');

    nameElement.textContent = theName;
    dateElement.textContent = theDate;
    amountElement.textContent = theAmount;
    deleteBtn.textContent = 'Delete';

    deleteElement.append(deleteBtn);

    tBody.appendChild(rowElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(nameElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(dateElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(amountElement);
    rowElement.appendChild(deleteElement);

    deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     
        //rowElement.parentNode.removeChild(rowElement); // In this way it only deletes the last inserted element
        /*
         You can use (this) to reference the object that fired the function. 

        'this' is a DOM element when you are inside of a callback function 
        */

        // this.parentNode.removeChild(this) // In this way only the button is removed
        // this.parentNode ===> td
        // this.parentNode.parentNode ===> tr
        // this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode ===> tbody

        this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode)
    });

    nameInput.value = "";
    dateInput.value = "";
    amountInput.value = "";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I have tried this and it still doesn't resolve the issue.  My app still only removes the last row element added to the page and only one delete button will work no matter how many rows I add.  It seems as though the click event on the delete button is tied strictly to the last row element added.

Comment: This worked, thank you very much.  A couple things in here I have not yet learned about so I really appreciate your help!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

this way:

```js
const
  myForm  = document.forms['my-form']
, tableTB = document.getElementById('tBody') 

myForm.onsubmit = e =>
  {
  e.preventDefault()
  let newRow = tableTB.insertRow()
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.name.value
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.date.valueAsDate.toLocaleDateString()
  newRow.insertCell().textContent = myForm.amount.valueAsNumber
  newRow.insertCell().innerHTML  = '<button data-action="del">Delete</button>'
  myForm.reset()
  }
tableTB.onclick = ({target}) =>  
  {
  if (!target.matches('button[data-action="del"]')) return
  target.closest('table').deleteRow( target.closest('tr').rowIndex )
  }
```

```css
label { 
  display : block;
  float   : left;
  clear   : both;
  width   : 5em;
  margin  : .5em;
}
input {
  display: block;
  margin  : .5em;
}
table  {
  border-collapse : collapse;
  margin          : 2em 1em;
  }
td,th  {
  padding    : .2em .8em;
  border     : 1px solid darkblue;
  }
thead { 
  background-color: aquamarine;
  }
```

```html
<form name="my-form">
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" size="26" placeholder="Where was the expense made?" required>

  <label for="date">Date:</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>

  <label for="amount">Amount:</label>
  <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" value="" required>

  <button type="submit">Add Expense</button>
</form>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name:</th> <th>Date:</th> <th>Amount:</th> <th>Remove:</th>
    </tr>    
  </thead>
    <tbody id="tBody"></tbody>
</table>
```

Have a look to [How to swap two rows depending on the direction using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67292718/how-to-swap-two-rows-depending-on-the-direction-using-javascript/67293067#67293067)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the 'e event' to go to parent, and after you can go to the element that you want and delete it.
i hope it's helpful